# Website is running slow. Firebug doesn't explain much

Tags: php, html, css, firebug, pageload

Been messing around with Firebug on a test website. Need some help regarding it.

This page is 2.7kb but takes 11.39 seconds to load:
http://puu.sh/8V9sk.png

Would someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: download firephp and see how long the queries take.

Comment: You could use an online tool like this: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ This will tell you what is taking so long to load and how you can improve it.

Comment: I said above how long this specific query takes. This query is the longest one and stops other elements from loading.

Comment: well than post the query

Comment: The picture located in the post above is the longest loading URL.

Comment: According to pingdom, your page is 1.9mb and takes 22s to load http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/c2rmbe/www.profiledt.co.uk/moodle

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you'd post the relevant code of the target document here and ask for help on a slow query (sql) or on an inefficient piece of php code. To post a picture with a long url, hoping for someone to type this in the browser, resulting in (much likely) a blank page is a joke.

Comment: I help you ask better questions by criticising you. Why do you think nobody was able to help you? Your setup maybe is well known for you, but for us, it's blackbox. You did nothing to help us analysing your problem and just point at a picture. The perfomance problem could have been caused by a lot of things. Therefore your question is bad. Better think about who is sitting on a "high horse".

Answer (score 2):

Hovering the [timeline within Firebug's *Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Timeline) provides some more detailed information on the network request timings. So you can see, which part of the request is slow.

[image: network request timings]

Regarding your screenshot the *Waiting* part (purple) takes the longest, which means that your server-side script takes some time to execute.

Though because client-side debugger tools like Firebug cannot provide information on why a script on the server-side is slow, you need to analyze the problem in your server-side script.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up allowing the site to cache all the web scripts allowing the page to load quicker. This can be done in Moodle via

Site Administration > Appearance > Settings.